# i2c Connection for MCP4725(Dac) with Esp8266 wemos d1 mini

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, i2c, wire-library

------------ *This question has been edited* ------------

*note*: Dac and Adc is12bits

my problem : I use two ESP. Using esp1, I read the Adc amount of the alternating signal (ECG) and send it to esp2 with UDP and I get it. Now, using the same amount of Adc, I would use the MCP4725 to convert the digital value of the Adc to the analog. But I don't know how to do it !

- Do you need sine lookup table like default library example again ??!
- If so, how is it done?!
- I wrote the following code right now, what is your opinion?
  Explain to me if my code is in error.

I just want the DAC output, to be the ADC signal input.

*Code*:

```
void loop () {

  int noBytes = Udp.parsePacket();
  String received_command = "";

  if ( noBytes ) {
    Udp.read(packetBuffer,noBytes);

    for (int i=1;i<=noBytes;i++)
    {
      received_command += char(packetBuffer[i - 1]);
    } 
    int dac_value ;
    dac_value = received_command.toInt(); 
    Serial.print("dac value: ");Serial.println(dac_value);
    aPin = dac_value ;
    if (!si.i2c_start((I2C_7BITADDR<<1)|I2C_WRITE)) {
      Serial.println("I2C device busy");
      return;
    }

    else{
      Serial.println("i2c is worked");
    }

    for (byte i=1; i<noBytes; i++){
      si.i2c_write(aPin);
      si.i2c_rep_start((I2C_7BITADDR<<1)|I2C_READ);
      si.i2c_stop();
      delay(50);
    }
  }
}
```

---

I use `#include <SlowSoftI2CMaster.h>`.

***si*** is: `SlowSoftI2CMaster si = SlowSoftI2CMaster(4, 5, true);`

Photo:
[image]

Comment: If the problem is how to interface the MCP4725, I recently answered a question about it, where is explained how to interface it correctly. Please read [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67043/software-i2c-sending-data/67044#67044). Also have a look at the `Wire` library and the MCP4725's datasheet

Comment: I'm waiting for answer..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will explain the basic principles and give some tips. This won't be about your code, since it is neither compilable, nor does it make much of a sense to me.

1. **The I2C Protocol:** An I2C connection always needs 2 lines, SDA (which carries the data) and SCL (where the master outputs the clock signal). The communication always get's started by the master with a START CONDITION. Then it transmits the first byte, which consists of the 7 bits long address of the slave device and one bit, that shows if a read or a write operation will be performed. The slave - if there is any with that address - will then respond with an Acknowledgement. The master will transmit it's data and end the transmission with a STOP CONDITION or start a new transmission with a repeated start condition.
2. **Choose the I2C library:** You are using the [SlowSoftI2CMaster](https://github.com/felias-fogg/SlowSoftI2CMaster) library because it is architecture independent. As you are a beginner, you should use the [SlowSoftWire](https://github.com/felias-fogg/SlowSoftWire) library, which is a `Wire`-like wrapper library. It gives you the same interface, as the `Wire` library. That is good for beginners, since this hides some of the complexity and most examples and tutorials use the `Wire` library (so you can often copy the code structure). You have to install both libraries (`SlowSoftI2CMaster` and  `SlowSoftWire`) in your libraries folder, but you only need to include the `SlowSoftWire` library. Please look at the examples, that come with that library. I will refer to that library in the following points.
3. **Using the `SlowSoftWire` library:** You can declare and initialize the library as in it's `simpleSlowWire.ino` example. For transmitting a new value to the DAC, you have to first use `beginTransmission()` to configure the library for a master write transaction. Then place the data bytes in the libraries buffer with `write()`. And finally do the transmission with `endTransmission()` (this is the only place during this process, where the real I2C action happens on the bus). When you begin the transmission with `beginTransmission()` you must provide the correct address of the DAC. This is meant without the direction bit. The address of the MCP4725 consists of the device code `1100`, the hardwired address pins A1 and A2, and the variable address pin A0. The hardwired address pins are most likely both zero, unless the manufacturer was ordered to program it otherwise (You can check the address with the scanner example). So, if you wire A0 to ground, the address will be `0b1100000`. If you wire A0 to 3.3V, it will be `0b1100001`. The direction bit will be handled by the library - you don't have to worry about it.

4.**The MCP's data protocol:** You cannot simply send the values from the ADC to the DAC. It except's a special data format, which includes command bits to determine it's mode of operation. I think, I have already described how the data is build up in principle and code pretty well in my answer to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67043/software-i2c-sending-data/67044#67044). If there is something special, that you don't understand, you can ask a new question and refer to that answer in it. Also I think, you should use the type `unsigned int` for the `dac_value`, since values from an ADC and values for a DAC both are positive only.

Please keep in mind, that building such projects needs some time investment, until you understand, what actually is happening there. If you use any chip, the datasheet of that chip is always a must read. I personally never haven't worked with the MCP4725. I just have read the datasheet. All information is already there.

Comment: Excellent description. That you said that the conversion of `adc` to `analog` can not be done easily, should the `lookup table` be used as `adafruit` examples? Or no?
So the `code` I wrote is not correct!

Comment: I don't know, what adafruit example you mean. Please provide a link. I don't see, where you would need a sine lookup table here, since you are just transmitting the signal from the ADC to the DAC. The DAC will output, what the ADC have read. A sine lookup table is only needed, if you want to generate a sine wave ftom the esp

Comment: this example [link](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MCP4725/blob/master/examples/sinewave/sinewave.ino)

Comment: I want to **reconstruct** the `DAC  output` using `ADC value` . . . . . . . .

Comment: `Adc` side wave form -->[link](https://www.onlinebiologynotes.com/electrocardiogram-ecg-working-principle-normal-ecg-wave-application-of-ecg/)

Comment: To just replicate the analog signal you don't need a lookup table

Comment: look this example : [link](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-output-devices/arduino-mcp4725-digital-to-analog-converter-tutorial/#Get_Your_MCP4725_I2C_Address)

Comment: @navid And what should I see in that example? Also they are using an Arduino (most likely the Uno), not the ESP as you. So most likely you cannot simply use the same library

Comment: Ah, I shouldn't be disappointed ..